# Compute $(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\frac{(k+n-1)!}{(k-1)!(k-1)!(n-k)!}$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, summation, factorial

1. Compute $(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\frac{(k+n-1)!}{(k-1)!(k-1)!(n-k)!}$
2. Define $a_{k,m}=\frac{(-1)^{k+m}(n+k-1)!(n+m-1)!}{(k+m-1)[(k-1)!(m-1)!]^2(n-m)!(n-k)!}$

Compute $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^na_{k,m}$

(Hint: one approach is considering the Hilbert matrix. Other approaches are also welcome. Thanks.)

Comment: The Maple command $$ (-1)^n*(sum((-1)^k*factorial(k+n+1)/((factorial(k-1)*factorial(k-1))*factorial(n-k)), k = 1 .. n)) $$ produces
$$ 1/6\, \left(  \left( -1 \right) ^{n} \right) ^{2} \left( n+2 \right) ^
{2} \left( n+1 \right) ^{2}{n}^{2}
$$

Comment: Are you sure? Your formula doesn't agree when $n=2$.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed a typo:$k+n-1$ insted of $k+n+1$. The Maple command $$(-1)^n*(sum((-1)^k*factorial(n+k-1)/((factorial(k-1)*factorial(k-1))*factorial(n-k)), k = 1 .. n)) $$ produces $n^2.$

Comment: I wonder how Maple came up with both formulas... How is it programmed?

Comment: The execution of the above command with $infolevel[sum]:=5$ gives some information about it.

Comment: After changing the order of the summation, the Maple command $$infolevel[sum] := 5; sum(sum((-1)^(k+m)*factorial(n+k-1)*factorial(n+m-1)/((k+m-1)*(factorial(k-1)*factorial(m-1))^2*factorial(n-m)*factorial(n-k)), k = 1 .. n), m = 1 .. n) $$ finds the second sum. See the output exported as a PDF file [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/778941314/sum.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, suppose we are trying to evaluate
$$(-1)^n \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k 
\frac{(k+n-1)!}{(k-1)!(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$

which is
$$(-1)^n \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k 
{n\choose k} k {n+k-1\choose k-1}.$$

Introduce
$${n+k-1\choose k-1} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n+k-1}}{z^k} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum 
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
(1+z)^{n-1} 
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} k \frac{(1+z)^k}{z^k}
\; dz.$$

Now observe that
$$x((1+x)^n)' = \sum_{r=1}^n {n\choose r} r x^r
= nx(1+x)^{n-1}.$$

We thus obtain
$$\frac{n\times (-1)^{n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z}
\left(1-\frac{1+z}{z}\right)^{n-1}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{n\times (-1)^{n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z}
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{z^{n-1}}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^n}
\; dz.$$

This evaluates to $$n\times {n\choose n-1} = n^2$$
by inspection.